# How to find if a point coords is inside rhombus coords

Tags: geometry

[image: MY RHOMBUS IMAGE]

```
A = 282, 34 (x,y)
B = 59, 198 (x,y)
C = 282, 359 (x,y)
D = 509, 198 (x,y)

E = 10, 10
```

So I have this image and I am trying to search if coords of point E are inside my rhombus, I am trying to figure out what is the formula, I did some searches but nothing that works for me.

Comment: This is not a programmatical but a mathematical problem ...

Comment: true, i will remove the php tag.

Comment: I know that this question is old but here one can find nice and clean answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/10717542/1714237

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to define the area inside.

First define the 4 rects like y = mx +b using the following expression:

> y = y1 + [(y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)]·(x - x1)

Where (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) are two points of the rect.

Now assume the following rects:

- r1 (contains A and B)
- r2 (contains B and C)
- r3 (contains C and D)
- r4 (contains D and A)

Assume x(E) = 10 and y(E) = 10 since E(10,10)

Then the area is defined as:

> r1(x(E)) < y(E) and r2(x(E)) > y(E) and r3(x(E)) > y(E) and r4(x(E)) >
>   y(E).

If all these conditions are verified, then the point is inside the rhombus.